# How to convert data to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Let's say we have a file (*.csv, *.txt ...) like :

```
Name,  Surname,     Age,  Occupation
Gino,  DiNanni,     19,   student
Anna,  Kournikova,  27,   programmer
```

<sup>*(I added those spaces just to make it readable here)*</sup>

I'm trying to create a JSON (BTW it's valid) like:

```
[
    {
        "gino_dinanni": [
            {
                "age": "19",
                "occupation": "student",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "anna_kournikova": [
            {
                "age": "27",
                "occupation": "programmer",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

accessible like e.g.

```
anna_kournikova.age    // 27
```

So far I have this http://jsbin.com/apapey/2/edit but this is giving me (awfully):

```
[["Age:19","Occupation:student"],["Age:27","Occupation:programmer"]]
```

I know how to use `.toLowerCase()` to create `anna_kournikova` and stuff, but I'm really lost in creating the right **JSON** "object". I would paste some better examples I tried before, but I erased them all in a fit of rage, now going back from scratch and I need your advice. Might be I'm missing a simple detail? Thanks so much!

Comment: looks like you'd need `x[1].anna_kournikova[0].age` with your sample JSON

Comment: @Thilo tx, but why the `[0]` if we use already the accessible property `.age` ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in javascript in the browser? Or on the server? Makes more sense to parse a csv file on the server. https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parser is an example that uses Node.JS (serverside javascript)

Comment: @rogchap Thans so much, I'm actually learning and trying to understand all that JSON thing, arrays, parsing, stringify, but after all that info and the strange looking JSON formats I've seen all around I'm trying to understand if I need to build it like a string inside `for` loops and than use some parse method or there's some simplest way to do it...

Comment: The `[0]` is because you've enclosed the fields for e.g. "anna_kournikova" in brackets `[]`.  It sounds like you don't want that, so just leave the brackets out for the fields beneath each person in your example data.  You don't specify what the server is running, but unless it's Node.js, I suspect @rogchap is on to something with asking about the server-side component here.  You mention hitting a URL and getting back this data.  That looks a lot like a Rails URL.  Is there more to the server-side story here?

Comment: @JimStewart (PC/XAMPP/nothing-special) thanks for your time. Let's say I have some URLs like `anna_kournikova.html` than I'd like to retrieve the right data from a flat-file but be able to play with `object-alike` JSON. Just to learn. The JSON format might be wrong now after reading all your comments, but can you guide me how to do it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to change the markup of your JSON, this would yield better results,

```
{
    "gino_dinanni": {
        "age": "19",
        "occupation": "student"
    },
    "anna_kournikova": {
        "age": "27",
        "occupation": "programmer"
    }
};
```

That way you can use `data.anna_kournikova.age`. As other users have suggested, your CSV should be parsed on the server side and you can just use `jQuery.getJSON( ...  )` to retrieve it

Comment: This looks so promising! But why than all over the place (even here on Stack overflow) i see formats like mine? with `[]` That's confusing me with arrays while building the right output...

Comment: Because what you are returning is an Array, and I'm returning an Object. Therefor the syntax is different when dealing with them.

Comment: +1'd. James, that's exactly what I was about!  only to play with objects and accessible properties! wow! I'm still in the mist, but it's gettin' clearer

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/ihivuj/2/edit

I've changed it to what I believe is your intended format.

The `..stringify` is probably not necessary for printing if you want to work with a real JSON object.  You were trying to work with some mixture of strings/arrays.

You can use the bracket syntax to add elements to objects, but do not treat them as arrays:

```
arr[oneData[0] + oneData[1]][headers[2]] = oneData[2];
```

You can't combine brace syntax with concatenation/variables for key names either.

Comment: +3'd. thanks so much, I was first looking at the other scripts and suggestions, now it's your turn ;) I'm playing with your demo and having some issues to recall `anna_kournikova.something`

Comment: and you're totally right, I lost hours just cause of that stringify. I knew it was returning a string, but it was the only thing that was visually familiar and readable to me in the console

Comment: hhh... I give up. I understand what you're saying but all I can see in the console is `[Object, Object]` ... and for all I try is giving me nothing. Please, how to use your demo? tx for your time

Comment: @Ginnani what browser are you using?  Because `[Object, Object]` is correct, and in Chrome you can expand each object to see its contents

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I just don't know how to follow up with retrieving any kind of data ( using the `console.log( ?*****? )` )...

Comment: @Ginnani are you saying you actually want to use the contents of the object?  If so, how/

Comment: You mean you want to evaluate the expression `anna_kournikova.occupation`?  There's no great way to do that .. `eval()` is a possibility, but it is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

You could see this page 
http://www.cparker15.com/code/utilities/csv-to-json/

The project in Github is https://github.com/cparker15/csv-to-json/issues

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can try some meta programming, using JavaScript :)

```
var json =[{"gino_dinanni": [{"age": "19","occupation": "student",}]},{"anna_kournikova": [{"age": "27","occupation": "programmer",}]}];

document.write(getAge('gino_dinanni'));

function getAge(name){
    return eval("json[0]."+name+"[0].age");
};
```

Comment: I hate using `eval` and I'm not sure my JSON example was the best one to achieve the wanted. But thanks! P.S, is that correct: `,}]}` ?